# str_extract - How to disable default regex

Tags: r, regex, stringr

library(stringr)

```
namesfun<-(sapply(mxnames, function (x)(str_extract(x,sapply(jockeys, function (y)y)))))%>%as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F)
```

So I am trying to use str_extract using sapply through two vectors, and the "jockeys" vector that I use as the pattern argument in str_extract, has elements with special characters like "-" or "/" that interfere with regex.
Since I want an exact "human" match if you prefer, and not regex based match, how can I disable regex from being the default matching manner?

I hope I got my point across!

Comment: are you looking for function `?stringr::fixed`

Comment: From the docs (`?str_extract`): "Match a fixed string (i.e. by comparing only bytes), using fixed(). This is fast, but approximate. Generally, for matching human text, you'll want coll() which respects character matching rules for the specified locale."

Comment: Is it a stand-alone function? I thought it was an argument within str_extract
I am relatively new to R and coding in general so I am a bit confused tbh

Comment: @ElMexicano the base regEx function have that `fixed` argument. `stringr` has a different approach.

Comment: Okk I found out how it works.thank you! :)